# How to write mappings in elsaticsearch for geopoint having lat lon and alt?

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, elasticsearch-plugin, geohashing, elasticsearch-2.0

**My_Json_File**

```
{
"addressInfo": {
    "city": "Wimsheim",
    "postcode": "71299",
    "geopoint": {
        "lon": 48.845877,
        "lat": 8.821861,
        "alt": 0.0
    }
},
"_id": "ac169008-aa5b-4b09-aa9e-3bf3018f316d"
}
```

- Pls give suggestion on how encounter this **"alt"** field in geopoint  and  **"_id"** field and also write a suitable mappings for above JSON file.

## Update 1

**My_Json_File**

```
{
"_id": "ac169008-aa5b-4b09-aa9e-3bf3018f316d"
"addressInfo": {
    "city": "Wimsheim",
    "postcode": "71299",
    "geopoint": {
        "lon": 48.845877,
        "lat": 8.821861,
        "alt": 0.0
    }
},
"prices": [{
    "fuelType": "DIESEL",
    "price": "52.09"
}, {
    "fuelType": "PETROL",
    "price": "66.20"
},{
   "fuelType": "AUTOGAS",
    "price": "66.20"
}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your place I would move "alt" out of geopoint and use mapping type "geo_point" which provides a lot of other options for further operations on geopoint field.

It would looks like:

```
{
    "_id": "ac169008-aa5b-4b09-aa9e-3bf3018f316d"
    "addressInfo": {
        "city": "Wimsheim",
        "postcode": "71299",
        "geopoint": {
            "lon": 48.845877,
            "lat": 8.821861,
        },
        "alt": 0.0
    },
}
```

and mapping should look like:

```
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "addressInfo": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "city": {
          "type": "string",
        },
        "postcode": {
          "type": "integer",
        },
        "alt": {
          "type": "float",
        },
        "geopoint": {
          "type": "geo_point",
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

where geo_point type field receives data like:

```
{"lat": 8.821861, "lon": 48.845877}
```

Comment: Why you have given **"type" : "nested"** ?..I am new to this so.

Comment: I prefer to use nested data type because it allows data arrays (array of objects) to be indexed and queried independently of the others. You can also use basic object type.

Comment: Pls check Update 1. I have changed my json file....How do you write a general mapping for that json file? I am bit confused because there **fuelType** and **price** are repeating. how do you write mappings for repeated things?

Comment: As I can see you have multiple fuelTypes and prices so you want them to repeat. Here you can also use nested object type for prices and just insert data as json.

Comment: can yu pls give me the mappings? Just like one you have given for earlier..pls

Comment: "prices": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "fuelType": {
          "type": "string",
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "float",
        },
}

Comment: can you help me in this also? [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762578/how-to-write-template-in-elasticsearch)