# Does Mongo-connector supports adding fields before inserting to Elasticsearch?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

- I have many docements in mongoDB. Mongo-connector inserts those data to elasticsearch. Is there a way, before inserting in to ES where we can add extra field to the document and then insert into elasticsearch? Is there any way in mongo-connector to do the above?

**UPDATE**

based on your **UPDATE 3** i created mappings some thing like this is it correct?

```
PUT my_index2
{
 "mappings":{
  "my_type2": {
  "transform": {
  "script": {
    "inline": "if (ctx._source.geopoint.alt) ctx._source.geopoint.remove('alt')",
    "lang": "groovy"
  }
},
"properties": {
  "geopoint": {
    "type": "geo_point"
  }
 }
}
}
}
```

**ERROR**

This what the error i keep getting when i tried to insert your mapping

```
{
   "error": {
  "root_cause": [
     {
        "type": "script_parse_exception",
        "reason": "Value must be of type String: [script]"
     }
  ],
  "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
  "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [my_type2]: Value must be of type String: [script]",
  "caused_by": {
     "type": "script_parse_exception",
     "reason": "Value must be of type String: [script]"
  }
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Now the mapping is getting inserted and getting the acknowledge as true. But when try to insert the json data like below its throwing error.

```
PUT my_index2/my_type2/1
{
 "geopoint": {
        "lon": 48.845877,
        "lat": 8.821861,
        "alt": 0.0
        }
}
```

**ERROR FOR UPDATE2**

```
{
   "error": {
  "root_cause": [
     {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse"
     }
  ],
  "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
  "reason": "failed to parse",
  "caused_by": {
     "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
     "reason": "failed to execute script",
     "caused_by": {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "scripts of type [inline], operation [mapping] and lang [groovy] are disabled"
     }
  }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

**ERROR 1 FOR UPDATE 2**

After adding script.inline:true, tried to insert the data but getting following error.

```
{
   "error": {
  "root_cause": [
     {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "field must be either [lat], [lon] or [geohash]"
     }
  ],
  "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
  "reason": "failed to parse",
  "caused_by": {
     "type": "parse_exception",
     "reason": "field must be either [lat], [lon] or [geohash]"
  }
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mongo-connector aims at synchronizing a Mongo database with another target system, such as ES, Solr or another Mongo DB. Synchronizing means 1:1 replication, so there's no way that I know of for mongo-connector to enrich documents during the replication (and it's not its intent either).

However, in ES 5 we'll soon be able to use [ingest nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html) in which we'll be able to define [processing pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/pipeline.html) whose goal is to enrich documents before they get indexed.

**UPDATE**

There's probably a way by modifying the [`formatters.py`](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/blob/v2.2/mongo_connector/doc_managers/formatters.py) file.

In [`transform_value`](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/blob/v2.2/mongo_connector/doc_managers/formatters.py#L61) I would add a case to handle `Geopoint`:

```
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        return self.format_document(value)
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        return [self.transform_value(v) for v in value]

    # handle Geopoint class
    elif isinstance(value, Geopoint):
        return self.format.document({'lat': value['lat'], 'lon': value['lon']})

    ...
```

**UPDATE 2**

Let's try another approach by modifying the [`transform_element` function](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/blob/v2.2/mongo_connector/doc_managers/formatters.py#L104) (on line 104):

```
def transform_element(self, key, value):
    try:
        # add these next two lines
        if key == 'GeoPoint':
            value = {'lat': value['lat'], 'lon': value['lon']}
        # do not modify the initial code below
        new_value = self.transform_value(value)
        yield key, new_value
    except ValueError as e:
        LOG.warn("Invalid value for key: %s as %s"
                 % (key, str(e)))
```

**UPDATE 3**

Another thing you might try is to add a [`transform`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/mapping-transform.html). The reason I've not mentioned it before is that it was deprecated in ES 2.0, but in ES 5.0 you'll have ingest nodes and you'll be able to take care of it at ingest time using a [`remove` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/remove-processor.html)

You can define your mapping like this:

```
PUT my_index2
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type2": {
      "transform": {
        "script": "ctx._source.geopoint.remove('alt'); ctx._source.geopoint.remove('valid')"
      },
      "properties": {
        "geopoint": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: make sure enable dynamic scripting, by adding `script.inline: true` to `elasticsearch.yml` and restart your ES node.

What is going to happen is that the `alt` field will still be visible in the stored `_source` but it will not be indexed, and hence, no error should occur.

With ES 5, you'd simply create a pipeline with a `remove` processor, like this:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/geo-pipeline
{
  "description" : "remove unsupported altitude field",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "remove" : {
        "field": "geopoint.alt"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: In mongo-connector there is a file called as **elastic2_doc_manager.py** which is config file, **I think**  mongo-connector  uses this to add doc to ES from MogoDB,  guess its written in python. If thats true, Is there a way were we can add field ,so that mongo-connector before inserting to ES it will add this field in the document and then insert it to ES?

Comment: Why i am asking this is beacuse the doc in MOngoDB contains a field **Geopoint**  filed which contains **lat , lon , alt** field. But ES Does not support  3D. The ES **"type" : "geo_point"**  take only **lat** and **lon**.  How do i solve this?

Comment: ES will not support 3D geo queries (although it [should now accept three values](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10510)), but what you want is just to store the altitude field separately?

Comment: In our project we have given **alt, lon, lat** as variables in **Geopoint class** and also inserted large amt of doc with specifying values  only to **lat** and **lon**  not specifying  any **alt**  value. So when ever we retrive doc in MongoDB we get **GeoPoint : { "lat" : 32.002, "lon" : 45.0215,  "alt" : "  " }**. So Removing this **alt** field from **GeoPoint.class** and then inserting doc to MOngoDB take a lot of time.

Comment: I was thinking like,editing config file and before mongo-connector inserts doc to ES, to that doc we add a field  like **geo_2d** which copies **lat and lon** of "GeoPoint" and then insert. so that in ES we can query location using this new field added.

Comment: What does currently happen if you run your synch process?

Comment: Since we are not specifying any mapings in ES.... Mongo-connector syncs everything from MOngoDB to ES. But problem is we are not able to query the **geopoint** in ES ..beacuse our **geopoint** has 3 fields where in ES supports only 2D.

Comment: How does the field look like in ES after the synch?

Comment: "geopoint": {
    "lat": 53.08412,
    "alt": 0,
    "valid": false,
    "lon": 8.64863
   } '

Comment: What I would do, is to specify the ES mapping explicitely and make `geopoint` a `geo_point` field. You need to delete the index and re-create it with the proper mapping and then you can run the synch again.

Comment: At the time of sync will there be no problem when the mappings encounters an alt filed in the doc that is to be indexed?..

Comment: The best way to know is to try it out :)

Comment: You're going to get a parse exception, indeed, because of the `valid` and `alt` fields. Removing these fields could be a job for the ingester nodes I talked about, indeed

Comment: Here is wat i tried. I had written mapping  like "geopoint" : { "type" : "geo_point" }. but when i passed doc containing GeoPoint : { "lat" : 32.002, "lon" : 45.0215, "alt" : " " } it gives mapping error.

Comment: There's probably a way by modifying the [`formatters.py`](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/blob/v2.2/mongo_connector/doc_managers/formatters.py) file and adding special handling for your Geopoint class

Comment: I dont know python. Its too much asking you, but still can you specify where in and how to make modification?.

Comment: the above **handle for geopoint** will  remove alt and adds just lat lon in the doc while inserting to ES?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, although I agree I have not tested it. But if you modify the file, you should be able to quickly see if that works or not

Comment: Ok. I will give the feedback on it.

Comment: Its giving error like:  > **File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/formatters.py", line 69, in transform_value
    elif isinstance(value, geopoint):
> NameError: global name 'Geopoint' is not defined**

Comment: Geopoint is the class name, right? Should be capital-cased like `Geopoint` and also make sure to import it.

Comment: doc in mongoDB has Geopoint field like this:  "geopoint" : { "lat" : 23.03, "lon": 45.035, "alt": 0}

Comment: Time allowing, I will try it out on my local MongoDB and see what's up

Comment: Sir try to have json doc in mongodb similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737559/how-to-write-mappings-in-elsaticsearch-for-geopoint-having-lat-lon-and-alt/36741536#36741536) "See Update1" and then try to insert it toES using mongo-connector

Comment: Will do and keep you posted.

Comment: thanks for your time. Will be waiting for your answer :)

Comment: SIr did you get any result?

Comment: is there anything that we can do to handle geo-points by the help of dynamic mappings in ES?

Comment: Sir i will test it and give you feedback

Comment: even after adding that line its not making any changes.  ES will have "geopoint": { "lat": 53.08412, "alt": 0, "valid": false, "lon": 8.64863 }  same format.

Comment: sir is there anything we can change in [elastic2-doc-manager](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/elastic2-doc-manager/blob/master/mongo_connector/doc_managers/elastic2_doc_manager.py)

Comment: even tried using dynamic mappings but it didnt work.

Comment: tried copy_to some thing like this :                                            'PUT a
{
  "mappings": {
    "b": {
      "properties": { 
        "geopoint": {
          "properties": {
            "lon": {
              "type": "double",
              "copy_to": "geopoint2d" 
            },
            "lat": {
              "type": "double",
              "copy_to": "geopoint2d" 
            },
            "alt": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "geopoint2d": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

Comment: its giving error like this : ' "type": "script_parse_exception",
            "reason": "Value must be of type String: [script]"'

Comment: Are you sure you properly copy/pasted the index definition? it's working on both ES 1.x and ES 2.x on my end. Please check again.

Comment: You have one too many closing parenthesis in the script, please check my update again.

Comment: Sir whats that "test" indicate? Is it just a  type name?

Comment: Oh, yes, you need to replace that with `my_type2` of course. Please see my revised UPDATE 3

Comment: i got confused...let me try once again :))

Comment: Check my **ERROR** thats what i get

Comment: I've slightly modified the index definition. Please try again and this time it should work.

Comment: pls check my **UPDATE 2**

Comment: Ok, that's great progress. I missed that but you also need to enable dynamic scripting, by adding `script.inline: true` to `elasticsearch.yml` and restart your ES node.

Comment: were in `elasticsearch.yml` should i add? at the end?

Comment: Yes, at the end is fine.

Comment: Pls see my **ERROR 1 ON UPDATE 2**

Comment: I think it's because of the `valid` field, which I forgot to remove... Replace the script string with this new one and try again `if (ctx._source.geopoint.alt) { ctx._source.geopoint.remove('alt'); ctx._source.geopoint.remove('valid'); }`

Comment: Pls can you show me the above modification in your **UPDATE 3**

Comment: Done, please check again.

Comment: @Val...yeee JSON data is getting inserted..Now can you show me how to query this geopoint?

Comment: Awesome, glad we made it work !!! Since we took care of the indexing part, I suggest you create another question for the searching part, I think this one was already quite a ride, don't you think?

Comment: yes..sir..sure thanks a lot for your help. I got how to query and got result too......I dont know how to thank you. thanks thanks alot...

Comment: If you learned something in this thread, then that's perfect! There are a few books, among which the [official one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/index.html) by ES folks and [another one](https://www.manning.com/books/elasticsearch-in-action) by Manning I contributed to

Comment: I too heard from others that manning is good. Now definitely i will by that....One last question. If i have any problem in ES further how do i connect to you? For ex. If i have a post how do i link it to you?

Comment: Just post a question, there are many people around here to help you out :-)

Comment: Sir sorry to distrub you. Do you know any solution for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982849/illegalstateexception-for-mixing-up-field-types)